# Why Two Methods for FirebaseDatabase Client Offline?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

FirebaseDatabase offers two methods to take a client offline:

[DatabaseReference.goOffline()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference)

> Manually disconnect the Firebase Database client from the server and
>   disable automatic reconnection. Note: Invoking this method will impact
>   all Firebase Database connections.

[FirebaseDatabase.goOffline()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase)

> Shuts down our connection to the Firebase Database backend until
>   goOnline() is called.

A call to `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline()` produces the expected results:

1. `ValueEventListener` for ".info/connected" fires for the disconnect
2. `OnDisconnect` action executes
3. `ValueEventListener`s for remote changes do not fire, those for local changes do
4. `CompletionListener`s do not fire

A call to `DatabaseReference.goOffline()` seems to have no effect.  None of the behavior listed above occurs.  Is it broken?  If not, how does it differ from the other `goOffline()`?

Comment: I can confirm the same behavior. Only FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline() seems to work.

Comment: @NizamMohideen: In my original post, I should have indicated the version of the library I tested against--now I don't remember.  I haven't retested using 9.2.1.  What version did you use?

Comment: This behaviour seen on 9.0.2

Comment: @qbix I am the CEO of Qbix, Inc. an app company formed around 2011. I see you're very active on SO - and congrats on helping many people! Unfortunately, your handle presents a trademark issue for us, since our company is literally named Qbix and has two trademarks registered in 2012. TM law requires us to be vigilant about protecting them. People might really get confused and think you are representing us on SO, which can lead to many problems for us from both a branding and legal standpoint. Can you please contact me to figure out the best way to resolve it? https://qbix.com/about -Greg

Comment: @GregoryMagarshak: I'll change my username in the next few days.

Comment: Thank you very much @qbix !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an oversight in the 9.x release.  `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline()` / `goOnline()` are the correct methods to use and `DatabaseReference.goOffline()` / `goOnline()` are indeed broken and will be removed in a future release.  Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: But, will **Firebase.goOffline()** and **Firebase.goOnline()** work?

Comment: This issue is still there in newer release. com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3. Only FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline() works and not  DatabaseReference.goOffline();