# Close Firebase database connection when leaving Android app

Tags: android, firebase, database-connection, firebase-realtime-database, activity-lifecycle

I made an Android app which receives realtime data from [Firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/). In my main Activity the user has to log in with e-mail and password and by success it opens a new Activity, which receives data.

It seems to be, that when the user leaves my app, the Firebase connection is still established. That is not good for the battery.

How is the way to manage the connection for closing and reopen the app? I think I need to use `onPause()` and `onResume()`. I found something like `goOffline()`, but I cannot found this method in the new Firebase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you may use the activity lifecycle methods like `onPause()`, `onStop()` on `onDestroy()` to close your connection.

Also, it seems Firebase still has a `goOffline()` method - https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/api/#firebase_goOffline.

Comment: Yes, but that seems to be only for the "old" firebase.I have only the class FirebaseApp (com.google.firebase) and there is no .goOffline()

Comment: The same methods exist in the latest Firebase SDKs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#goOffline()

Comment: @DenisBanach, I doubt it. Otherwise Firebase would restructure their documentation to reflect that change.

Comment: Ah, okay thanks, now I found it. But it is in another class : FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Time").goOffline(); In older SDK it was Firebase.goOffline(), like I understand.

Comment: @DenisBanach: I'm curious to know the results of your changes.  There are actually [two ways to go offline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571761/why-two-methods-for-firebasedatabase-client-offline), and when I last tested them, I got different results.  If you could leave a comment on that question, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the `goOffline()` and `goOnLine()` methods is to remove `ValueEventListeners` and `ChildEventListeners` [when they are no longer needed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#detach_listeners).  My experience (with SDK 3.X only) is that Firebase will automatically disconnect after about 1 minute when then are no listeners registered and no other reason to be connected, such as a pending write.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently added Firebase database to my App, but noticed occasionally high battery usage, and it appears to be linked to my App keeping the radio active (radio active for 1 hour 30 mins in 10 hours, but app usage approx 5 minutes).

I believe that this is linked to Firebase database as I have disabled the in-app purchase broadcast receiver which is the only other network element.  I don't have any open listeners (I'm using single-value events), but some of the transactions are mutable, so it's possible one of them has failed to complete, and is regularly re-trying.  Database persistence is off.

I'm currently testing the following simple addition to pause/resume (got to get some code in the answer :-) ) :

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    if (FirebaseDatabase.getInstance() != null)
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOnline();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {

    super.onPause();

    if(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()!=null)
    {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline();
    }
}
```

And so far, so good.  ** The main thing to note is switching activities, requires you to have this in every app that uses Firebase (I had a sign-in activity which stopped functioning as it was reading the username from the database) **

5/12/16 - update after a couple of weeks of testing.  The high battery use returned yesterday.  I'm testing primarily on Lollipop, and there's loads of complaints about the radio being left open for other apps.  Others testing my App on Android M don't report any problems, so it's possibly a Lollipop issue.  I'm going to continue to test, this time trying to remove unnecessary transactions to see if this helps...  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: One update to this - just noticed that I'd made the reference to the database static as I was previously using persistence, and

Comment: fat fingers...   
        if(mFirebaseDatabase==null)
        {
             FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
             mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        }

Comment: I'm wondering if the reference hadn't been static, then the database connection would've been closed automatically.  So perhaps goOffline() / goOnline() are only needed when using static reference.  I'll update if I get a definitive answer...      must learn how to use Stack Oveflow.  Apolgies

Comment: 4 days later, and no battery problems, so I believe the problem for me was solved by removing the static on the database reference