# Firebase.goOffline () и Firebase.goOnline () будут удалены из firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[I read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571761/why-two-methods-for-firebasedatabase-client-offline) that Firebase.goOffline () and Firebase.goOnline () will be removed from firebase. Who knows if this is true or false ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The (4+ year old) post you're referring to was about `goOffline`/`goOnline` methods that were introduced on `DatabaseReference` by mistake. That problem has since then long been fixed.

There are no plans to remove the `goOffline`/`goOnline` methods from `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()`. As Michael says in the same post:

> `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().goOffline()` / `goOnline()` are the correct methods to use